# MySQL order by date until a specific date, after it reverse order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, navicat

Ok, so I have a table something like this

```
+----+-------+------------+
| id | title |    date    |
+----+-------+------------+
|  1 | aaa   | 2018-08-13 |
|  2 | bbb   | 2018-08-02 |
|  3 | ccc   | 2018-07-06 |
|  4 | ddd   | 2018-07-16 |
|  5 | fff   | 2018-07-13 |
+----+-------+------------+
```

and I want to sort it by date column ascending, but only until a specific date, after that I want to sort it descending, like this

```
+----+-------+------------+
| id | title |    date    |
+----+-------+------------+
|  4 | ddd   | 2018-07-16 |
|  2 | bbb   | 2018-08-02 |
|  1 | aaa   | 2018-08-13 |
|  5 | fff   | 2018-07-13 |
|  3 | ccc   | 2018-07-06 |
+----+-------+------------+
```

I thought I could use `UNION`, but either I don't know how to use it, or it doesn't accept `ORDER BY` clauses specified in each `SELECT`.

**EDIT:** I probably didn't explain myself so good. In my query I would need this to sort ascending by date all of the rows after a specific date (>= some date, in this case let's use 2018-07-15) and all of the rows before to be sorted descending.

Comment: Here's a variety of techniques... you probably only really need one or two of them http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58a8ac/20

Comment: @Strawberry Can you put it as an answer, as this one is the only one that seems to work properly.

Comment: Quite interesting, I didn't figure something like this was so complex to achieve.

Comment: @Rafael for me it was as I'm not that awesome with mysql

Comment: I wasn't satisfied with this problem... so I created a similar one with union, but I see some logic in it so I will post the answer.

Comment: Nice exercise though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this with a single `order by` and no subquery:

```
order by (case when date >= @date then 1 else 0 end),  -- put more recent first
         (case when date >= @date then date end) asc,  -- order the first group ascending
         date desc  -- order by second group descending
```

Answer (score 2):

With reference to the groundwork laid down by D-Shih...

```
SELECT id
     , title
     , date
  FROM 
     ( SELECT *
            , CASE WHEN date <'2018-07-15' THEN @i:=0 ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
         FROM t
            , (SELECT @i:=0) vars
        ORDER  
           BY date
     ) x
 ORDER
    BY i=0, i, date DESC;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58a8ac/20

You probably don't really need all the techniques shown above, but I'm just making this stuff up as I go along...

Comment: You're da best.

Comment: Using two `order by`s and a subquery is unnecessarily expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this union with subquery:

```
select * from 
(select *,ord=0 from tablename where id=2
union
select *,ord=1 from tablename where id<>2)a
order by ord asc, date desc
```

Comment: It works partially, it does separate those 2 dates, but it does not sort them differently.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing exactly the dates you want to use, you could do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        concat(1,'-',@firstquery := @firstquery + 1) as rownum, table_name.* 
    FROM 
        table_name, 
        (SELECT @firstquery:=0) fq 
    WHERE 
        date_column <= '2018-08-05' 
    ORDER BY 
        date_column ASC) a
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        concat(2,'-',@secondquery := @secondquery + 1) as rownum, table_name.* 
    FROM 
        table_name, 
        (SELECT @secondquery:=0) sq 
    WHERE 
        date_column > '2018-08-05' 
    ORDER BY 
        date_column DESC) b
ORDER BY rownum ASC
```

It is quite big, but in this case I'm emulating the rownumber based on each subquery and concatenating that for ordering later. Meaning you could order backwards also at some point.

What I like about this one is that we have the order specified in the rownum based on each item ordered previous to the union.

Answer (score 0):

@D-Shih has nearly got it right...

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY (CASE
  WHEN `date`>"2018-07-06" THEN 'date'
  ELSE DATE("2018-07-06")
) ASC,
`date` DESC;
```

You could do it with a UNION but this gets messy quickly.

You can also implement the CASE statement as LEAST()

Comment: It does not produce what I want in MySQL, the comment from @Strawberry on my question is the one that works.